# How to use Task.Factory.FromAsync with IRequestChannel?

Tags: wcf, async-await

I create a ChannelFactory of IRequestChannel:

```
ChannelFactory<IRequestChannel> channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IRequestChannel>(endpoint);
IRequestChannel outputChannel = channelFactory.CreateChannel(address);
outputChannel.Open();
responseMessage = outputChannel.Request(message);
```

I want to apply the Task-Based Asyncronous pattern.
Since IRequestChannel doesn't have async methods I need a way to use the outputChannel.BeginRequest and outputChannel.EndRequest.

I believe this can be done using:

```
Task.Factory.FromAsync()
```

How can I use the BeginRequest/EndRequest in combination with the FromAsync ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of searching I came to following solution:

```
 using System;
 using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;

 public static class RequestChannelExtensions
 {
     public static async Task<Message> RequestAsync(this IRequestChannel      requestChannel, Message message)
     {
         // this will be our entry that will know when our async operation is completed
         var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<Message>();

         try
         {
             requestChannel.BeginRequest(message, asyncResult =>
             {
                 try
                 {
                     var resultMessage = requestChannel.EndRequest(asyncResult);
                     taskCompletionSource.TrySetResult(resultMessage);
                 }
                 catch (OperationCanceledException)
                 {
                     // if the inner operation was canceled, this task is cancelled too
                     taskCompletionSource.TrySetCanceled();
                 }
                 catch (Exception ex)
                 {
                     // general exception has been set
                     taskCompletionSource.TrySetException(ex);
                 }
             }, null);
         }
         catch
         {
             taskCompletionSource.TrySetResult(default(Message));
             //propagate exception to the outside
             throw;
         }

         return await taskCompletionSource.Task;
     }
 }
```